# java xml要素の正規表現による文字列置き換えについて

Tags: java, 正規表現, xml

xmlで特定の文字列を変換したいです。
`<${特定のタグ_1}><${特定のタグ_2}>${特定の値_1}$({特定の値_2})</${特定のタグ_2}></${特定のタグ_1}>`
上記のような構成の時に、特定のタグ_1がある場合にmatcherのfindで一致をさせました。
特定の値_1に紐づいた特定の値2を消さずに特定のタグ_2を削除する場合にはどうすればいいのでしょうか。
イメージとしては以下になります。
`<${特定のタグ_1}><${特定のタグ_2}>[[[revision(${任意の値})]]]</${特定のタグ_1}></${特定のタグ_2}>`
`<${特定のタグ_1}>[[[revision(${任意の値})]]]</${特定のタグ_1}>`
※revision,任意の値に関しては変更をせず保持をしたまま、
値だにある特定のタグを抜き取りたいです。
以下は現在の記述です。
`${String変数}.replaceAll("\\<${特定のタグ_1}\\>.*?\\[\\[\\[revision\\(.*?\\)\\]\\]\\]", "${ここに何を入れればいいかわからない。}");`

Comment: XMLを扱うのであれば、XMLパーサーを使用した方がいいように思います。正規表現を使用すると、正しく実装できていることを保障するのが難しい、文字列によっては異常に時間がかかる可能性がある、というのが主な理由です。

Comment: xmlが文字列で渡ってきたものに対する処理なのですが、SAXParserなどで一度出力したものに大して改めて処理を行うほうがいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 「一度出力」する必要は無いですよ。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。やってみます。